# Kohana ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method Request::redirect()

Tags: kohana-3

I'm using Kohana 3.3.0 and i have a controller which is supposed to save blog articles to a database then redirect to the homepage, my code is as follows:-

```
class Controller_Article extends Controller {

const INDEX_PAGE = 'index.php/article';

public function action_post() {

$article_id = $this->request->param('id');
$article = new Model_Article($article_id);
$article->values($_POST); // populate $article object from $_POST array
$article->save(); // saves article to database

$this->request->redirect(self::INDEX_PAGE);
}
```

The article saves to database but the redirect line gives the error:-

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method Request::redirect()
```

Please let me know how i can do the redirect.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, Request::redirect is not longer exists. So in order to easily to move from 3.2 to 3.3 I extented Kohana_Request class and added redirect method. Just create **Request.php** in **classes** folder and write

> ```
> class Request extends Kohana_Request {
>
>     /**
>      * Kohana Redirect Method
>      * @param string $url
>      */
>     public function redirect($url) {
>        HTTP::redirect($url);
>     }
>
> }
> ```

So you will be able to use both **Request::redirect** and **$this->request->redirect**

Answer (score 8):

You're getting the Exception because as of Kohana 3.3, `Request` no longer has the method `redirect`.

You can fix your example by replacing

`$this->request->redirect(self::INDEX_PAGE);`

with

`HTTP::redirect(self::INDEX_PAGE);`

Answer (score 4):

in your controller `$this->redirect('page');`

Answer (score 1):

$this->redirect('article/index');